# MySQL запрос, выборка из таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется две таблицы: `catalog`, `catalog_alias`.

В `catalog` идёт список позиций с полями (все писать не буду смысла нет)

```
id, article, brand_id.
```

В `catalog_alias`

```
id, from_analog_article, from_brand_id, to_analog_article, to_brand_id
```

Сейчас запрос имеет вид:
ЗАПРОС ИСПРАВИЛ !!!! (до этого был то что тестил, случайно вставил.)

```
select catalog.*,brands.name as brand_name,partners.name_original FROM catalog 
INNER JOIN brands ON brands.id = catalog.brand_id 
INNER JOIN partners ON partners.id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM pricelist WHERE id=catalog.pricelist_id) WHERE `article` = ''
```

Но он не использует `catalog_alias`.

Помогите переписать.

Данные имеют вид:

```
catalog:
article  brand_id 
oc121    104
7918     10

catalog_alias:
f_a_a  f_b_i  t_a_a  t_b_i
oc121  104    7918   10
```

Т.е по вводу `7918` или `oc121` должен вывести одно и тоже. 2 строки (ну или более).

При этом даже если в `catalog` - отсутствует позиция с артикулом, но алиас на неё имеется он должен вывести строку. Пример удаляем из `catalog` `oc121` и в запросе указываем его то бишь должен в итоге вывести позицию из `catalog` с артикулом `7918`.

Comment: вот в этой части `INNER JOIN catalog_alias ON catalog_alias.to_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.to_brand_id=catalog.brand_id` замените `AND` на `OR`

Comment: Зачем ? Привязка должна быть артикул, бренд. Т.е артикул может быть не один такой, но у каждого бренда - только один.

Comment: так. запрос вы исправили. теперь в нем вообще не используется таблица catalog_alias...чтобы связать catalog и catalog_alias используйте запрос `select *
from catalog 
join catalog_alias ON (catalog_alias.from_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.from_brand_id=catalog.brand_id) or (catalog_alias.to_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.to_brand_id=catalog.brand_id)`

Comment: Да, всё круто, я тоже пытался так )) Но есть нюанс, при вводе алиаса в нашем случае 7918. он выведет именно строку из каталога где имеется артикул 7918 ! Но надо, чтобы вывел и к чему он привязан ! (oc121)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что если написать запрос вот так `select *
from catalog 
join catalog_alias ON (catalog_alias.from_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.from_brand_id=catalog.brand_id) or (catalog_alias.to_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.to_brand_id=catalog.brand_id)
WHERE catalog_alias.to_analog_article='7918'`, то из catalog выбирается только 1 запись вместо двух?

Comment: Да, всё окей, чуток дописал и выводит как надо, благодарю ! Сделай как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из обсуждений в комментариях пришли к решению ниже:

```
select * from catalog join catalog_alias 
ON (catalog_alias.from_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.from_brand_id=catalog.brand_id) 
OR (catalog_alias.to_analog_article=catalog.article and catalog_alias.to_brand_id=catalog.brand_id) 
WHERE catalog_alias.to_analog_article='7918'
```